# Turning any Text with any Coding into byte array C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, encoding, arabic-support

Hello My Firends Here i have an algorithm which convert string to byte array
the English text it works fine but in anothor lanugages just like arabic it's not i know because it's a unicode but i want to make an algorithm that can convert any type of text

> here is my code:

```
 public static byte[] StringToByteArray(string x)
    {
        byte[] bytes = new byte[x.Length * sizeof(char)];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(x.ToCharArray(), 0, bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        return bytes;
        }
```

so when i pass text with english the bytes length is **normal** but when i pass text in anothor languages it's **normal*2** because there is a **0's**

so what i want here is to convert any type of text so please help me

Example:arabic text will generate byte array just like 
**40 0 4 0 10 0 214 0 7 0** so I have zeros every odd index and the byte array length will be 2 times larger

> **ps:** i tried alot of algorithm on the internet and from another posts but none of them really solve the proplem

Comment: Its not clear what you are trying to do. Convert a hex string to a byte array? Are you expecting the hex string to be in some other language?

Comment: Maybe I'm not entirely clear on what you want, but wouldn't byte[] bytes = UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes(hex); do it?

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a `System.Text.Encoding` to get bytes from a unicode text and also convert back to original unicode string like this:

```
string source = "Your arabic text goes here...";
var byes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(source);
string dest = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byes);
```

Comment: Does it works for any text just like Hebrew and english or just arabic?